# Display text next to img in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains an img, p tag and h6 text. I want to float the text on the right side of the picture and not wrap it under.

I have tried floating left and right and clearing, displaying inline-block on div and floating img, but I cannot get it to look right.

```
<div class="col">
  <img src="images/homepage-blue-icon.png" class="body-img" title="Me" alt="Me" align="left" />
  <h6>Blueberries</h6>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The code, as given, gives me the desired output of image on the left followed by the text on the right. I would advise you to check your body-img class and col class

Comment: `align=left` is obsolete for almost 2 decades, use `float:left`in your CSS file or style tag.. If image has a known width, a margin-left of equal size will be sufficient.

Comment: Or you case use `display: flex`

Comment: @marciojc flex is not for the best here, you have at least 3 tags :) , grid would be perfect ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a few ways:

`float` and `margin`

```css
h6,
p {
  margin :0 0 0 55px;
}

.body-img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="body-img" title="Me" alt="Me" />
  <h6>Blueberries</h6>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
</div>
```

---

`float` and `padding`

```css
h6,
p {
  padding :0 0 0 55px;
}

.body-img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="body-img" title="Me" alt="Me" />
  <h6>Blueberries</h6>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
</div>
```

---

`display:grid`  a tutorial among others : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
.col {
display:grid ;
grid-template-columns:60px 1fr;
}
.col> * {
grid-column:2;
}
.col img {
grid-column:1;
grid-row:1/span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="body-img" title="Me" alt="Me" />
  <h6>Blueberries</h6>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
</div>
```

---

`display:table`/`table-cell;` if you wrap the image . it can allow vertical-alignement too, hover the image to see it align in the middle.

```css
.col {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.left:hover {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="left"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="body-img" title="Me" alt="Me" /></div>
  <h6>Blueberries</h6>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
  <p>Healthy and nutritious</p>
</div>
```

Comment: one last thing, is there a way to make the text and p tag the same height as the pic?

Comment: @cal what size is your pic ? i would think that the display will do (grid or table) can you add more information and eventually make a new question ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can put them into a table with one row?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <img style='' src="img.jpg" class="body-img" title="Me" alt="Me" align="left" />

    </td>

    <td>
      <div>
        <h6>Blueberries</h6>
        <p>
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
          magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
          exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
          velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
          occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
           mollit anim id est laborum."
        </p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```